# Arrester 'minus' connected to the 'plus' of a capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, circuit-protection

I am repairing 'Siemens SITOP power 20' power supply. I have to draw its circuit to better understand it and a notice a bizarre design decision. Can you help me to understand it?

It has an arrester which one connection stands on the 'plus' of DC and another connection should be a 'minus'. That 'minus connection is goes through induction coil and connected to a 'plus' (!) of the capacitor. How does it possible?

On photos please note plus and minus from AC-DC bridge and how it is connected to arrester and capacitor.

(220V/380V AC as an input + one neutral, 3 thermistors and 3 varistors as protection layer, next is three-phase rectifier (diode bridge for 3 phase current) which converts AC to DC, next is a filter which 'plus' goes to arrestor)

[image: 1st side]
[image: 2nd side]
[image: reversed engineered so far circuit, have to do it on plain paper because of lack all required components in top list circuit software]

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic and links to the datasheet of the arrester.

Comment: I still working on a whole circuit, it isn't ready yet. Also Siemens's official circuit is not publicly available on the web (at least I haven't found it). Please check photos of related part of the schematic. I don't remember exact name of arrestor, but it contains this in name 'epcos 90'

Comment: What you're calling an arrestor here looks like a gas discharge tube, which don't have polarity. With a schematic someone here could probably figure out the purpose of it, but as the question stands it's unlikely to be answered--you don't need a full circuit schematic, but if you can draw up a schematic of what you've reverse-engineered so far, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: Part number(s) on the gas discharge tubes/varistors/arresters?

Comment: @Hearth updated with circuit scheme, name of this element closely matched to this https://www.epcostdk.com/datasheet/epcostdk/ES90XP.pdf (but there is no full match).

Comment: @winny I could share exact numbers when I will get back to the lab tomorrow.

Comment: @Hearth could you please help me better understand the difference between arrestors and gas discharge tubes? It looks as they are synonyms. However, I have found information GDT are unipolar, but often negative: "The polarity can either be positive or negative depending on the design or function, however, most are generally negative". On another side this element on the board is EPCOS ES 90 07 o which is classified as an arrestor. Regarding others elements: thermistors  NTC 10, varistors S14 k550,

Comment: A gas discharge tube is a type of surge arrestor.

Comment: You diagram shows a direct shortcut between + and - after the rectifier. This is surely wrong.

Comment: @Elmue, there is a filter right after rectifier, plus and minus from rectifier goes into the filter. Plus from filter goes to arrestor, regarding of minus it is not clear yet where it goes. May be do you mean minus of arrestor goes to a plus of the capacitor? That's concerns me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit strange, but **EPCOS** arrestors marked as red have positive polarity - they are unipolar instead of bipolar. In this case plus from arrestor goes to a plus of capacitor which is fine.

By specification one of two arrestor's electrodes should be 'grounded', connected to the ground. It gives me an idea they are always bipolar. However, technically surge breakdown should be channelled to anything capable for it, so a capacitor will fit this use case as well.